# Computation of two covariances between time series (one with both series at same time $t$, one with one lagged time series)

Tags: covariance, time-series

We have a random walk defined as:
$$m_t=m_{t-1}+u_t$$
with $u_t$ representing a noise i.i.d. with expectation 0 and variance $\sigma^2_u$. Then, we define:
$$p_t=m_t+q_tc$$
where $q_t=+1$ or $-1$ and $c$ is a constant. Notice also that $q_t$ are assumed to be serially independent and independent form both $m_t$ and $p_t$. We also have that $\epsilon_t=u_t+c(q_t-q_{t-1})-\theta \epsilon_{t-1}$, with $\epsilon_t$ representing a zero-mean white noise process and $\theta$ an arbitrary parameter.
Could someone help me to understand, step by step, how to get that:
$$\operatorname{Cov}(q_t,\epsilon_t)=c$$
$$\operatorname{Cov}(q_t,\epsilon_{t-k})=0, \forall k\geq 1\text{?}$$
As to $\operatorname{Cov}(q_t,\epsilon_t)$, I have just get to the point that, since $E[q_t]=0$ and $E[\epsilon_t]=0$, ${Cov}(q_t,\epsilon_t)={E}[q_t\epsilon_t] = E[q_tu_t+cq_t^2-cq_tq_{t-1}-\theta q_t\epsilon_{t-1}]=0+cE[q_t^2]-0-\theta E[q_t\epsilon_{t-1}]=c\times1 - \theta E[q_t\epsilon_{t-1}]=c-\theta E[q_t\epsilon_{t-1}]$, and I do not know how to show that $\theta E[q_t\epsilon_{t-1}]$ equals $0$. On the other hand, as to $Cov(q_t,\epsilon_{t-k})$, I do not have any clue on how to show it is zero $\forall k\geq 1$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Thank You for the tip